# How to generate Sitemaps for AJAX based sites?

Tags: node.js, xml, express, ejs, sitemap

So I created a site based on YTS API with express and ejs. Every thing is running fine but the problem is that I want to create a sitemap for submitting it to google but I am unable to generate a sitemap because all online tools fail to crawl my site.

All pages are based on AJAX requests.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

There are several websites to do that.

If you wanna do it manually then check this (Officially by Google) https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2017/12/rendering-ajax-crawling-pages

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17190878/14229991 according to this ajax-crawling-pages is deprecated by google can you tell me some sites that will help me generate the sitemap